# Obtener datos de este json en flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart

Buenas quiusiera hacer una consulta ya anteriormente he trabajado con jsons en flutter sin problemas pero este json me esta causando problemas para obtener los datos

el json en cuestion es el siguiente [Datos del JSON](http://utp.ideas-web.net/data.json)

Para esto utilizo la herramienta de https://app.quicktype.io/ la cual me ayuda a generar el codigo mas rapido
ahora mi problema esta en esta parte en el momento de acceder a los valores este es mi codigo

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:apxltracker/JsonParse/getPlayerData.dart';
import 'package:apxltracker/Services/translations.dart';

final String urlApi0 = "https://api102ty.re/bridge?12&platform=";
final String API = "&auth=xFAfEAkmF4bu";

Future userGlobalData(String userid, String platform) async {
  var urlGlobalF = Uri.parse(urlApi0 + platform + "&player=" + userid + API);

  final Response response = await http.get(urlGlobalF);
  //final Response response = await http.get(urlGlobalF, headers: {'Authorization': API});
  //final GetPlayerData = getPlayerDataFromJson(response.body);
  final getPlayerData = getPlayerDataFromJson(response.body);
  return getPlayerData;
}

class GlobalData extends StatefulWidget {
  const GlobalData({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GlobalDataState createState() => _GlobalDataState();
}

class _GlobalDataState extends State<GlobalData> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: userGlobalData("yunier10", "X1"),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
            case ConnectionState.active:
              return Container(
                  child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  Text(
                    Translations.of(context).text('loading'),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Teko", color: Colors.red, fontSize: 26.0),
                  )
                ],
              ));
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(

                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/img/error.png"),
                      height: 100.0,
                    ),
                    Text(Translations.of(context).text("wrong"),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            fontFamily: "Acme",
                            color: Colors.red)),
                  ],
                ));
              }
              return GridView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                itemCount: 1,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                  childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1),
                ),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                  final Global getData = snapshot.data.global[index];

                  return GlobalDataView(
                    username: getData.name,
                  );
                },
              );
          }
        });
  }
}



class GlobalDataView extends StatelessWidget {

  final username;





  const GlobalDataView({
    Key key,
    this.username
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    final ViewcardGlobal = Card(
      elevation: 3.0,
      child: Hero(
        tag:username,
      child: Material(
        child: InkWell(

          child: GridTile(
            child: Text(username),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    ) ;
    return ViewcardGlobal;
  }
}
```

en la parte del itemcount no se que colocar ya he puesto

> snapshot.data.global.length

y nada y en esta parte

> final Global getData = snapshot.data.global[index];

me envia mensaje de error

> Class 'GetPlayerData' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Instance
> of 'GetPlayerData' Tried calling:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de dar vuelta al asunto para acceder a los datos resulta que debia cambia las lineas

> final Global getData = snapshot.data.global[index];

por

> final GetPlayerData getData = snapshot.data;

y para obtener el dato de nombre por ejemplo seria

> getData.global.name

de esta manera ya pude obtener los datos doy por cerrado el caso

Answer (score 1):

pero estas aseguro que al momento de mandar la URL y el API  , puedes mostrar porque consola lo que te trae el JSON ??? recuerda que este tipo de JSON Debes recorrerlo para obtenerlo la información , trata de meterlo en un FOR para que puedas leerlo con un print(result) , mediante consola

Te adjunto un ejemplo algo similar

```
Future<List<User>> getUser() async {
//Future<String> getData() async {
String url = "TU URL";

String token = 'adssadadadasdad';

var response = await http.get(url, headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  //'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'Authorization': '$token',
});
var data = json.decode(response.body);

List<User> users = [];
for (var item in data) {
  User user = User(item['id'], item['nombre']);
  users.add(user);
}
print(users.length);
return users;
```

si te muestra en un PRINT los datos puedes llenar asi el LISTVIEW

```
 future: getUser(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Cargando"),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data[index].nombre));
                });
```

Comment: si estoy seguro que llega respuesta me llega el json la cosa esta al momento de acceder a los datos como mencione arriba si en el Future del llamado del json hago un > print(getPlayerData.global.name); me retorna el valor con el nombe del usuario.       la cuestion es como acceder desde el future builder